# How to correctly load event calendar on Jquery Model dialog box on rails(Next and Previous buttons on event calendar not properly working)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events

I developed [event calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) to load on Model dialog box but problem is when I try to click Next or Previous it redirect to default calendar path. But I need to show that result on same model dialog box. How can I do this ? Please expert give me some solution for this problem ?